# How to classify images using SVM

Tags: r, computer-vision, classification, svm, libsvm

I have train and test folders which consist of `PNG` handwritten characters and symbols. I want to perform classification using `SVM` in `R`. I'am able to classify when the handwritten images are in the same folder, but I want to have two folders each for train and test respectively. The input is `PNG` images. How to classify images by `SVM` considering different folders for test and train data?

Comment: whats your question?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to classify separate characters? In which case your problem is going to be complex to solve with a single SVM. SVM is useful for yes or no problems . Problems that have a binary solution for classification.Otherwise you have to compare multiple runs of the SVM to compare a pair of outcomes at a time and trickle down the outcome that is more likely.

Comment: ya exactly. Iam classifying separate characters. I have upper case alphabets . i want 26 classes each for one alphabet. How to perform multi class svm using R.

Comment: SVM does not do multiclass by itself. However, you can set up a system of SVMs that do multiclass classification. Look up "one vs one", "one vs all", and "hierarchical multiclass" classification.